# Django to heroku deployment issue

Tags: python, django, heroku, dependencies, pygobject

While attempting to deploy my django project, I am running into a strange error:

There is a dependency that I didn't use, and uninstalled, that is still trying to load with `requirements.txt` during the build.

I have since uninstalled all of the dependencies, removed it from `requirements.txt`, run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, and yet it still tries to load it, which crashes the deployment.

`PyGObject` is the dependency.

workflow:
Procfile - `web: gunicorn solarsystem.wsgi`
ran - `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`
the dependency is no longer showing after uninstalling it.

however during build:

```
 Collecting PyGObject
remote:          Downloading PyGObject-3.42.0.tar.gz (716 kB)
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: started
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
...
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
...
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

and here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.3.4
autopep8==1.5.7
boto3==1.17.108
botocore==1.20.108
click==8.0.1
cm-rgb==0.3.6
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.3
django-appconf==1.0.4
django-compressor==2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-libsass==0.9
django-material==1.9.0
django-materializecss-form==1.1.17
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
django-sass-processor==1.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
hidapi==0.10.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
jmespath==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
libsass==0.21.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.3
mpld3==0.5.5
numpy==1.21.2
Pillow==8.3.1
psutil==5.8.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
pycairo==1.20.1
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
rcssmin==1.0.6
rjsmin==1.0.12
s3transfer==0.4.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

I have tried multiple variations of `requirements.txt` and `Procfile` configs, looked all over my source code for any imports of `PyGObject` or `gi`, and there are none. I have also searched the `PyGObject` docs, and other stack overflow resources without success.

to reiterate, I would like to somehow completely remove it in some other fashion, or somehow add an ignore statement somewhere for that dependency so I can successfully deploy.

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib uses PyGobject, that's why it tries to install PyGobject when you install requirements.txt file,
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Try using the following commands. it will probably solve the issue of installing PyGobject

```
python3 -m pip install --no-use-pep517  cm-rgb
```

or

```
sudo pacman -S python cairo pkgconf gobject-introspection gtk3 
pip3 install pycairo to build and install Pycairo
pip3 install PyGObject to build and install PyGObject
```

Comment: this was a great start to the issue! however, the problem persists with uninstalling it too. That said, I will now go through all of them and see what other dependencies here may also utilize PyGObject. thank you for the idea!

Comment: @deitz88 you can try the above solution. probably it will resolve the issue and you would be able to download PyGobject without errors.

Comment: https://github.com/gfduszynski/cm-rgb/issues/45

Comment: @hamza-hassan-44 i came across that thread as well, and saw many different ways to try and install PyGObject, but all of them continue to fail for me for some reason - that's why I want to remove any way if to trying to install during the deploy, plus I have no need for this dependency in the project anymore.